# nodejs fluent-ffmpeg split long file into multiple small files based on seconds given

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to split 10 minute audio mp3 file to 10 different 1 minute files using `fluent-ffmpeg` package in `nodejs`.
We can do this for `ffmpeg` package using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i file.wav -f segment -segment_time 60 -c copy parts/output%09d.wav
```

But I want the same functionality in `fluent-ffmpeg` for `nodejs`. What is the name of the method?

```
return ffmpeg(audioFile)
    .toFormat('wav')
    .audioChannels(1)
    .audioFrequency(44100)
    .audioBitrate('128')
    .on('error', (err) => {
        //error
    })
    .on('progress', (progress) => {
        //progress
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      // on complete
    })
```

I tried looking at documentation for the segment feature for `fluent-ffmpeg` but couldn't get any solution.